# Does any Tolkien book state why Elros chose the gift of men?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion

Why would he want to be parted from his twin?

Does it say in the Silmarillion? Unfinished Tales? Children of Hurin? History of Middle-Earth?

Comment: _Cherchez la femme_.

Comment: One wonders if Elros was the "older" twin, in which case he was the de facto head of both the House of Beor and the House of Hador, making him the logical choice to be named King of the Edain. In that case, I would posit that Elros made the natural choice, and *Elrond* chose differently to be "out of the way", so to speak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From *Akallabêth*, the fourth part of *The Silmarillion*:

> At the feet of the mountain were built the tombs of the Kings, and hard by upon a hill was Armenelos, fairest of cities, and there stood the tower and the citadel that was raised by Elros son of Eärendil, whom **the Valar appointed to be the first King of the Dúnedain**.

So **divine appointment** is one possibility. Perhaps he was told he had to be King of the Dúnedain and for that he had to choose mortality.

---

From Appendix A of *Lord of the Rings*:

> Elros **chose to be of Man-kind and remain with the Edain**; but a great life-span was granted to him many times that of lesser men.

This suggests another reason: he **wished to stay with the Edain**. Some elves, including Elros's father Eärendil and niece Arwen, chose mortality for their partner's sake; perhaps Elros chose it for the sake of a race he cared for.

Comment: Don't forget, either, that his dad would rather have chosen to stay with the race of Men, but chose otherwise for his wife's sake.

Comment: @MattGutting Yep; he (as well as Arwen) was who I was thinking of in the last sentence. I've now edited them in explicitly.

Comment: I think it extremely unlikely that Elros was made to be mortal by the decree of the Valar. More likely, is that he was appointed to be the King after he chose his mortal destiny.

Answer (score 1):

I've searched through my PDF version of *History of Middle-Earth* and found these references:

> but Elros his brother chose to abide with Men.

*- Quenta Silmarillion*

> But to Elros, who chose to be a
> king of men, still a great span of years was granted,

*- The Fall of Numenor*

This gives at least some idea that Elros wished to remain among men and even wished to be their King.